# OpenGL Error 1281 in fragment shader (only by using block interface)

Tags: c++, opengl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have a very confusing error somewhere in the vertex or fragment shader. The rendering works when I do not actively use the block interface in the fragment shader. But when I am using it error 1281 occurs. Below you see the working vertex and fragment shaders. The error is discusse below the code.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 430

in layout (location = 0) vec3 position;
in layout (location = 1) vec4 color;
in layout (location = 2) vec3 normal;
in layout (location = 3) vec2 uv;
in layout (location = 4) vec3 tangent;
in layout (location = 5) int materialId;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix;
uniform mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform mat4 ml_matrix = mat4(1.0);


out VS_OUT {
    vec4 color;
    vec2 texture_coordinates;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 tangent;
    vec3 binormal;
    vec3 worldPos;
    int materialIdOut;
} vs_out;

out vec4 colorOut;

void main()
{
    vs_out.color = color;
    vs_out.texture_coordinates = uv;        
    mat3 normalMatrix = transpose ( inverse ( mat3 ( ml_matrix )));
    vs_out.normal = normalize ( normalMatrix * normalize ( normal ));
    gl_Position = ( pr_matrix * vw_matrix * ml_matrix ) * vec4 ( position, 1.0);

    colorOut = vec4(vs_out.normal,1.0);
}
```

WORKING fragment shader (normal is used as color):

```
#version 430


uniform vec3 cameraPos;
uniform mat4 ml_matrix;
uniform mat4 vw_matrix;
uniform sampler2D texSlots[32];

in VS_OUT {
    vec4 color;
    vec2 texture_coordinates;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 tangent;
    vec3 binormal;
    vec3 worldPos;
    int materialIdOut;
} fs_in;


out vec4 gl_FragColor;
in vec4 colorOut;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = colorOut;
}
```

If I am trying to use the block interface in the fragment shader like

```
gl_FragColor = fs_in.color;
```

or

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(fs_in.normal,1.0);
```

the error 1281 occurs. I really do not see why this is not working.

**EDIT: solution:**

there where in fact two problems:

1. `int` was interpreted as `float`
   From the application I send the material attribute to the shader by using
   `glVertexAttribPointer(SHADER_MATERIAL_INDEX, 1, GL_INT, ...);` which leads to the problem, that attribute was interpreted as float in the shader
   By using `glVertexAttribIPointerEXT(SHADER_MATERIAL_INDEX, 1, GL_INT, ...);` we can overcome this problem
2. The program linking was not successful "error c5215 integer varying must be flat" which leads to a change in the vertex and fragment shader.

   out VS_OUT {
   vec4 color;
   vec2 texture_coordinates;
   vec3 normal;
   vec3 tangent;
   vec3 binormal;
   vec3 worldPos;
   flat int materialIdOut;
   } vs_out;

and

```
in VS_OUT {
    vec4 color;
    vec2 texture_coordinates;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 tangent;
    vec3 binormal;
    vec3 worldPos;
    flat int materialIdOut;
} fs_in;
```

Now everything works perfect

Comment: Where do you get error 1281 (GL_INVALID_VALUE)?

Comment: How is vs_out conencted to fs_in?

Comment: @AdrianKrupa: If I am substituting gl_FragColor = colorOut; by gl_FragColor = fs_in.color; the error occurs.

Comment: @immibis: the shaders are linked in the same program. the blocks have the same name and exactly the same members (ordering, types and naming). therefore, as far as I know, the should be linked automatically

Comment: What does the glGetShaderInfoLog/glProgramInfoLog say? Btw.: The blocks do not have the same name. One is called vs_out, the other one fs_in.

Comment: @bobby they do not have the same name, one is called vs_out and one is called fs_in.

Comment: @bobby this error you get from C++ code. Put some here. Also as BDL mentioned, how do you check shaders compilation/linking?

Comment: @immibis: only the block names are important and they are the same.

Comment: @bobby what are `fs_in` and `vs_out`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very unintiutive. The variable "int materialIdOut;" was incorrectly "initialized". It seems, that when I was using the block interface, the problem occurs. If not, all worked fine

EDIT:
see solution in the question post